# Gradle fails to resolve github project (simple)

Tags: android-studio, github, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use this library in my project: https://github.com/haldertaer/android-maps-utils

When I use `implementation 'com.github.haldertaer:android-maps-utils:0.5'` in Gradle, I get the following error: `ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.haldertaer:android-maps-utils:0.5`

And, yes, I already have this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error? I do not see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [project documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/#quick-setup), the correct way to define the dependency for the official library is

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

**Update**

As per your comment, you want to resolve the forked version rather than the official one using JitPack. When using JitPack, `version` must be one of "Release tag, commit hash or `-SNAPSHOT`" ([Building with JitPack](https://jitpack.io/docs/#building-with-jitpack)). You can try with

```
com.github.haldertaer:android-maps-utils:master-SNAPSHOT
```

or

```
com.github.haldertaer:android-maps-utils:72b39c8
```

Comment: No, I want the forked version of the project, which is: https://github.com/haldertaer/android-maps-utils

Comment: @user11315386 Without changing any Gradle definitions, then forked repos aren't available from Maven Central

Comment: @user11315386 Updated the answer, hope it helps!